# Sum of $i$ times $(i-1)^\text{th}$ Fibonacci Number

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, fibonacci-numbers

Consider the expression $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i \cdot F_{i-1}$$, where $F_{0}=0, F_{1}=1, F_{2}=1, F{3}=2,$ etc. Is there a closed formula for this? If so, find it.

Comment: Yes, there is a closed form.

Comment: By the way, what definition of Fibonacci are you using - what is $F_0?$

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you run into trouble? Perhaps you could even tell us where you encountered the problem; that would let us know the most useful way to proceed. [Adding context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) will prevent others from closing your question.

Comment: It is more polite to ask for a solution rather than demanding one ("If so, find it"). Often people react unfavorably to a demanding tone.

Comment: Now that the question is on-hold, you need to [add context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) so that others might vote to reopen your question. Unless your question is reopened, your question will not get any more answers.

Answer (score 2):

Take the generating function of $F_n$ (which is absolutely convergent for $|x|<\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}+1}$:
$$ 
\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}F_i x^i\Rightarrow \frac{1}{1-x-x^2}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}F_i x^{i-1}
$$
Take derivatives of both sides:
$$
\frac{x^2+1}{\left(1-x-x^2\right)^2}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i F_i x^{i-1}\Rightarrow
$$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i F_i x^{i-1}+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}F_i x^{i-1}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(i+1)F_i x^{i-1}=\frac{2-x}{(1-x-x^2)^2}
$$
And take the Taylor-series at $x=0$.

Comment: How does this give a finite sum?